To integrate javascript within Mailchimp HTML Builder
I want to embed gamification code from dot.vu, which is in JavaScript into the Mailchimp HTML builder. But based on my reading, Mailchimp HTML builder cannot support JavaScript. I tried to embed it and sent a test email. As a result, the JavaScript part didn't appear on the sent email. Need assistance on this issue.
Need assistance on how I can embed the gamification link so that it'll appear within the marketing email being sent from Mailchimp.

Please clarify is your question how to embed JavaScript or how to create a link in an email?  JavaScript will likely get stripped by most mail clients or blocked.  Perhaps describe what you really want to accomplish here rather than asking how to do it the way you want to do it.

Apologies for the confusion. The goal is to include the gamification features within an email marketing send from Mailchimp. The gamification code generated was in javascript form. As per my reading, Mailchimp can't support javascript. Alternatively, i did embeded the gamification link within the email. So the users will need to click on the embedded link and redirected to the game page. Was wondering whether are there any other alternatives to achieve this.
